# Samsung S7 photos that were compressed by Windows are now are over 40GB each and I can’t open them

Tags: windows, compression, jpeg

[image: Full image]

Archived [file found here](https://we.tl/t-v8P9Wmumnm).

This is a random picture that is 2MB when compressed but 45GB when decompressed

I stored the files from the phone on a Windows 10 laptop that had little memory left and started doing the automatic compression so all the folders, respectively pictures have this icon.

[image]

Fast forward a year and I wanted to see the photos but realized I couldn’t. Tried opening it with GIMP and online software... moving it to a different computer. It didn’t work.

The phone has since been wiped so this is the only version left of the files.

My guess is that the files are not actually compressed but it tries to decompress them anyways?

Here is how it looks on the said laptop:

[image]

Comment: How are you retrieving the photos from your device? What device are you retrieving them from? Have you tried copying the file through any of the cloud providers from your phone to your computer? Rather than showing us the end result it would be better for you to show us screenshots of the original size, what you are doing, and then the result. Just the result is not likely to be that helpful.

Comment: Ok i tried being more explicit

Comment: I tried to download your file several times.  One time the download reached 100% but never finished.  Another time the download wouldn't start.  The hosting site also has a message that the file will be deleted in 7 days, which means the question will not have long-term value on the site even if the file was accessible.  If these are any kind of normal picture, 40+ GB suggests that something got corrupted.  With just the information in the question, it will be hard to know exactly what happened or how to go about any potential recovery.

Comment: Are these pictures in or from your OneDrive pictures folder? OneDrive has a feature to save space on your machine by syncing the data to the cloud and then deleting it locally: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/11/06/windows-10-tip-save-disk-space-onedrive-files-demand/#8ESkHGbwAqF23HF4.97 You might be able to go to your online version of OneDrive and search for the "real" files there: https://onedrive.live.com/